# UML notation class relationships Java

Tags: java, uml, relationships

If I have a class called `Location` and a class called `Maze` which has a field which is an array of 'Location' objects as shown below then is this a composition relationship because 'Maze' typically has more than one 'Location' object?

[image]

Is this a correct relationship between the 2 classes? or is composition only if it has one object of another class?

Also say if `Maze` has a constructor which takes an parameter of type `Space` such as: `public Maze(Space space){}` then what would be the relationship between `Maze` and `Space`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good question to ask about composition is "If the parent is destroyed, is the child destroyed".  In composition (as opposed to aggregation), the lifecycles are intertwined.  In this case, if maze is destroyed, all the locations should be destroyed as well, making it clearly a composition relationship.

Comment: Loosely yes.  But a person can "own" a book, but that doesn't mean that when the person dies, the book dies too.  Choose your verbs wisely.  Perhaps "consists of" is better.

Comment: Good point.  No.  The diamond should be at the container, not the contained class.

Answer (score 0):

This is both a composition and a many to one relationship. `Maze` has many `Locations`.